# Proper use of filters in ElastichSearch

Tags: search, filter, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I type in Elasticsearch this document:

```
    {
    "id":"b35d0a97-5f00-41a0-a321-30d387a65692",
    "products": ["http://...."],
    "parameters": {
        "Gender": ["Women"],
        "Waistline": ["Empire"],
        "Is_customized": ["Yes"],
        "Dresses length": ["Knee-length"],
        "Silhouette": ["Sheath"],
        "Neckline": ["Square collar"],
        "Sleeve length": ["Short"],
        "Style": ["Casual"],
        "Material": ["Acetate","Spandex","Viscose"]
    },
    "globalCategory": "99a74e52-d122-4177-b77c-12427d84f365"
}
```

I'm trying to find it using the filter:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {

            "filter": {

                    "term": 
                    {
                        "globalCategory": "99a74e52-d122-4177-b77c-12427d84f365"
                    }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

But Elasticsearch can't find nothing! What is my mistake, tell me, please?

Comment: Can you reproduce the entire set of operations you did. From creating index ( if any ) , creating mapping ( if any ) , indexing the document and finally issuing the search.

Comment: Please could you post your mapping?

Comment: to add the data in the index, I used C # and library NEST. Mapping is automatically generated from the class of C #. GlobalCategory field is of type Guid and converted into a 'string' when mapping.

Comment: Because of the wide variety of values ​​in the 'parameters' mapping in JSON format has a size of about 3 megabytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this, you used the default mapping. The field globalCategory than becomes a string which is analysed using the standard analyser. Therefore you have a few terms in your index:

```
99a74e52
d122
4177
b77c
12427d84f365
```

My best bet in this situation would be to add a mapping and make the field globalCategory not_analyzed, that way the field is used as one term and the filter will do it's work.

Comment: I used the attribute not_analyzed field globalCategory:
`[ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]`

 
`public Guid GlobalCategory { get; set; } `

But it did not give any result...

Comment: Can you add the current mapping to your question? You can use http://server:port/your_index/_mapping

Comment: `{
    "mappings": {
        "productclustermodeles": {
            "properties": {

                "globalCategory": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "products": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

`

Comment: I found a mistake! What would have earned POCO mapping need to make a call: `client.CreateIndex ("products_index", s => s
.AddMapping <ProductClusterModelEs> (m => m.MapFromAttributes ())`
);
As soon as I did then was: `"globalCategory": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"}`. Filter began to work as I need.